# Ansible version on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS doesn't seem latest after repository set up

Tags: ubuntu, ansible

At the time of writing, the current version of Ansible for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (focal) appears to be  [2.10.11-1ppa~focal](https://launchpad.net/%7Eansible/+archive/ubuntu/ansible?field.series_filter=focal)

However, when I follow the steps[1] on that page and subsequently try to install, according to the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#installing-ansible-on-ubuntu) I seem to get a different version[2].

[1] Repository install steps

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ansible/ansible
sudo apt-get update
```

[2] After `apt install`

```
$ ansible --version
ansible 2.9.6
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install *ansible-base*. It's a moving target atm. See [Releases and maintenance](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/reference_appendices/release_and_maintenance.html).

```sh
shell> ansible --version
ansible 2.10.10

shell> dpkg -l | grep ansible-base
ii  ansible-base                          2.10.10-1ppa~focal
```